# Angular6 catch timeout error

Tags: angular, angular6

with this code I can catch all the exceptions, except the when the server is anavailable.
Do you have any idea about how should be handle ?

```
return this.http.post<User>(this._appSetting.ebit.base_url "rested/login/login", JSON.stringify(params), httpOptions)
                  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `timeout()` operator to catch a timeout. It's measured in milliseconds so `10000` would be 10 seconds.

```
return this.http.post<User>(this._appSetting.ebit.base_url "rested/login/login", JSON.stringify(params), httpOptions)
              .pipe(timeout(10000), catchError(this.handleError));
```

Comment: it can't reconize the timeout do i have to import something?

Comment: Find it !
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators/timeout';

Comment: you need to import timeout as:
**import { timeout } from "rxjs/operators;**