# Angular http.get() detecting call timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm struggling to figure out how to detect a request timeout with Angular http and promises. I'm using the following code to format a response from my API and it is currently timing out which I want to handle with an error message, the code here does work when my API return an actual error message just it is not even getting hit when the API times out.

I could not find any documentation about Angular http having a way to handle timeouts so anything would be helpful, thanks!

Code:

```
/**
  * GET from the API
  * @param params  What to send
  * @param path    Where to go
  */
public get(path, params): Promise<any> {
  return this.formatResponse(
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl + path, params)
  );
}

/**
  * Takes the API response and converts it to something usable
  * @param response Promise of formatted data
  */
public formatResponse(response): Promise<any> {
  return response
    .toPromise()
    .then(r => r.json().data)
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('hitting error');
      const errors = e.json().errors;
      let error = 'Something went wrong, please try again in a few minutes.';

      if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        error = errors[0].message;
      }

      // Create alert
      this.utilities.createAlert(
        'Whoops!',
        error
      );

      // Throw the error
      throw new Error(error);
    });
}
```

When monitoring in the network tab I see:

> Failed to load resource: The request timed out.

Comment: What error code is shown in the network tab? `.catch()` will catch HTTP errors.

Comment: @Matt `Failed to load resource: The request timed out.`

Comment: What do you see in the network tab? A HTTP timeout should be code 408.

Comment: It has no error code.

Comment: if you use rxjs, you could use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405688/angular6-catch-timeout-error,  I don't know if something similar can be done via promises.  also with rxjs you can catch errors sooner and do your own thing with it or generate something special

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this

```
public get(path, params): Promise<any> {
  return this.formatResponse(
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl + path, params).pipe(timeout(10000), catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

and create the error handler as you like.  the rest would stay the same.